# When to use fcheck() or fcheck_files() and for what?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, manpage

In Linux kernel module, while calculating absolute path by file descriptor,  *fcheck()* or *fcheck_files()* are used. I didn't get much information about these functions. I need to know which function is appropriate for which situation. When these functions fails? Where to find documentation about such functions? As stated [here](http://osxr.org/linux/source/Documentation/filesystems/files.txt),

> ... To look up the file structure given an fd, a reader must use either fcheck() or fcheck_files() APIs....

But no information is given about which function should be used when and for what.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fcheck()` is defined as a preprocessor macro in [include/linux/fdtable.h, line 90](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L90) as:

```
#define fcheck(fd)      fcheck_files(current->files, fd)
```

And `fcheck_files()` is defined as a function in [include/linux/fdtable.h, line 77](http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/include/linux/fdtable.h#L77) as:

```
static inline struct file * fcheck_files(struct files_struct *files, unsigned int fd)
{
        struct file * file = NULL;
        struct fdtable *fdt = files_fdtable(files);

        if (fd < fdt->max_fds)
                file = rcu_dereference_check_fdtable(files, fdt->fd[fd]);
        return file;
}
```

They are not two functions thus no need to confuse which is appropriate for which function.

The `fcheck()` function is used to

> Check whether the specified fd has an open file.

Comment: Thanks @WayneSudo for this nice answer, but what if I use this function for file descriptor and not for directory descriptor? Does I have any way to check fd, whether it's for file or directory?

Comment: In short, I get _NULL_ for empty directory, but not for file. What do you mean **open file** here? Please elaborate.

Comment: It means if fd is valid, then return the corresponding file struct, if not return NULL.

Comment: When a fd should be considered as invalid fd?

Comment: In which cases this will return _null_? 1) fd for non empty dir, 2) fd for empty dir, 3) fd for file.

Comment: Each running process has its own fd table, if the fd checked by fcheck() is not on the fd table, it would be considered as invalid fd and the function would return NULL. For example, a fail open() would return -1 as an invalid fd.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the dir is empty or not, whenever a file or other i/o stream is opened, it would get its own fd in the fd table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88171/discussion-between-ntn-and-wayne-sudo).